# StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries сразу для нескольких методов Split

Tags: c#, строки, split

Приветствую. Можно ли использовать перечисление StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries сразу для нескольких методов Split, не прописывая его отдельно для каждого из них?
Например здесь:

```
        String[] keywords = textBox1.Text.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        String[] authors = textBox2.Text.Split(new char[] {'\n', '\r'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        String[] countrys = textBox3.Text.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Comment: Можно, например через расширяющий метод.

Comment: Или просто свой отдельный статический метод.

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать переменную:

```
var remove = StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries;
var keywords = textBox1.Text.Split(new[] { ' ' }, remove);
var authors = textBox2.Text.Split(new[] { '\n', '\r' }, remove);
var countrys = textBox3.Text.Split(new[] { ' ' }, remove);
```